# Windows 10 Explorer keep crashing and restart

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

Just I upgraded my laptop from windows7 to windows10 thru auto upgrade. Upgraded was done succuessfully however noticed an issue that Explorer.exe keep crashing and restart every one min.

I've checked for a soultion in microsoft forumn and super user but nothing worked.

I can see the following error in windows Event Log.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
        <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
        <Level>2</Level> 
        <Task>100</Task> 
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-11-30T08:46:33.704824800Z" /> 
        <EventRecordID>5238</EventRecordID> 
        <Channel>Application</Channel> 
        <Computer>SAK-PC</Computer> 
        <Security /> 
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data>explorer.exe</Data> 
        <Data>10.0.10586.0</Data> 
        <Data>5632d4c0</Data> 
        <Data>IDTNC64.cpl</Data> 
        <Data>1.0.6421.0</Data> 
        <Data>50237ef0</Data> 
        <Data>c0000005</Data> 
        <Data>0000000000001154</Data> 
        <Data>2530</Data> 
        <Data>01d12b4b78cea0f1</Data> 
        <Data>C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe</Data> 
        <Data>C:\WINDOWS\system32\IDTNC64.cpl</Data> 
        <Data>e0f1a07c-9813-4145-9569-5e62cb1c6e32</Data> 
        <Data /> 
        <Data /> 
    </EventData>
</Event>
Message :
Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632d4c0
Faulting module name: IDTNC64.cpl, version: 1.0.6421.0, time stamp: 0x50237ef0
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000001154
Faulting process id: 0x2530
Faulting application start time: 0x01d12b4b78cea0f1
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\IDTNC64.cpl
Report Id: e0f1a07c-9813-4145-9569-5e62cb1c6e32
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

As suggesed in microsoft forum

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

I ran those two commands, got status "nothing affected"

Also windows 10 auto update is up-to-date. Some one please help, thanks.

Comment: There's an MS article for you described problem, dont know if you are using W10 Technical preview though. 
Take a look here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3020114

Comment: Does this happen while in Safe Mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eventlog entry shows you the cause:

```
<EventData>
        <Data>explorer.exe</Data> 
        <Data>10.0.10586.0</Data> 
        <Data>5632d4c0</Data> 
        <Data>IDTNC64.cpl</Data> 
        <Data>1.0.6421.0</Data> 
        <Data>50237ef0</Data> 
        <Data>c0000005</Data> 
        <Data>0000000000001154</Data> 
        <Data>2530</Data> 
        <Data>01d12b4b78cea0f1</Data> 
        <Data>C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe</Data> 
        <Data>C:\WINDOWS\system32\IDTNC64.cpl</Data> 
        <Data>e0f1a07c-9813-4145-9569-5e62cb1c6e32</Data> 
        <Data /> 
        <Data /> 
    </EventData>
```

The control panel file `IDTNC64.cpl` in version 1.0.6421.0 causes the crash. This looks like a control program for an audio/sound driver. So update the driver or delete the file `C:\WINDOWS\system32\IDTNC64.cpl`

Comment: Hi, many thanks. I just renamed IDTNC64.cpl and the explorer.exe stopped loop restarting. Can you suggest how to reinstall the driver.

Comment: go to the manufacturer site and look for the latest driver version